# What does "base ten ASCII" mean?

Tags: ascii

Maybe I'm doing a terrible job of using the Google, but these specifications for [Bencoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bencode) keep referring to something known as "base ten ASCII", which makes me think it's different than regular ASCII. Could someone explain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_system) is explicitly stated to avoid confusion (although one might argue that base-10 is generally assumed by default).

Consider this: given the text representation of "12" (in ASCII), what is the numeric value?

- If it is base-10, that would be 1 * 10 + 2 -> 12.
- If it was base-8 (oct), it would be 1 * 8 + 2 -> 10.
- If it was in base-16 (hex), it would be 1 * 16 + 2 -> 18.

However, in Bencode it's *always* base 10, so 42 (the integer) is encoded as "i42e".

---

A use of base-16 over base-10 might be to save a byte in longer ASCII-encoded numbers or to ensure a consistent pad size .. *but* base-10 fits in better with how numbers are commonly written and makes a Bencoded file more accessible. (That said, Bencoded files are generally not "human editted".)

Comment: Thanks that was really informative! Great examples.

Comment: "makes a Bencoded file more accessible" - Bencoded files usually contain binary data, so I don't think they're very accessible to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

"Base 10 ASCII," as used in this context, is not one thing. It just means that a base 10 number is represented using ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to binary? Looks like the number 5 is shown in its base-10 form `5` instead of the binary version `101`.

Answer (score 0):

`integer encoded in base ten ASCII`

that means numbers like you count with eg 1, 9, 11, 123. ASCII is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart

Your looking in the Dec Column

encoded in base 10 means the number, and ASCII meaning the letter representation of the numbers, for easier reading in a text editor

Comment: So if I were to open a base ten ASCII encoded file with my simple command line text editor, it should be readable?

Comment: `Integers are encoded as follows: i<integer encoded in base ten ASCII>e
The initial i and trailing e are beginning and ending delimiters. You can have negative numbers such as i-3e. Only the significant digits should be used, one cannot pad the Integer with zeroes. such as i04e. However, i0e is valid.` So yes

Answer (score 0):

Base 10 ASCII means, you write out the ASCII code of the character in base 10, instead of base 16.

A would thus be written as 65.  The space character would be written as 32.  m would be written as 109.

This contrasts with (for example) URL-encoded ASCII, which is base 16.  In URL encoding, %41 is A, %20 is space, and %6D is m.